# Concatenate regexed values with sliced values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, concatenation, slice

I have the following function that concatenate values from column B with values from column L:

```
function ConcatenateJS() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    var valuesB = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lr,1).getValues();  //Get values for column B
    var valuesL = sheet.getRange(2, 12, lr,1).getValues();  //Get values for column L
    var results = [];                               //Create a empty array to be filled concatenated elements

    //Add items to results
    for(var i=0; i<lr; i++){
        results[i] = [valuesB[i][0]+"-"+valuesL[i][0]];
    }

    //Post back to column 1 starting on row 2
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, 1).setValues(results);
}
```

I need to take only the first three letters of *valuesB* (so no spaces and special characters) and only the last eight letters of *valuesL*.
How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*first three letters of valuesB (so no spaces and special characters)*"? What should you get for `v alue`? Is it `v` or `val`?

Comment: In column B there are some names (like "Johnny", "S-Uper Nick", "S4mm3r" etc.). I need to take only first three letters of these names, excluding numbers and special characters (so "Joh", "SUp", "Smm").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns objects which are apparently convertable to strings, you can

1. Convert to a regular string with [the `String` constructor as a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String) to convert it to a string.
2. Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) using a regular expression:

   - `/[^a-zA-Z]/g` which will replace anything that is *not* a letter
   - `/[^0-9]/g` which will replace anything that is *not* a number
3. Call [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) on what remains to get the characters you want.
   If you pass a negative index to `.slice()` it takes items from the end.

So everything you need would be:

```js
function lettersOnly(value) {
  return String(value).replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
}

function numbersOnly(value) {
  return String(value).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}

function formatValues(str1, str2){ 
  var value1 = lettersOnly(str1).slice(0, 3);
  var value2 = numbersOnly(str2).slice(-8);
  
  return [value1 + "-" + value2];
}

console.log(formatValues("abcdef", "0987654321"));
console.log(formatValues("a1_b -2c-d4e5f", "q-1*r-2+s-3't-4-u-5_v-6 w-7,x-8.y-9(z-0"));
console.log(formatValues("ab6", "xyz12345"));

console.log(formatValues("Johnny", "0987654321"));
console.log(formatValues("S-Uper Nick", "0987654321"));
console.log(formatValues("S4mm3r", "0987654321"));

const objB1 = { toString() { return "Johnny"; } };
const objB2 = { toString() { return "S-Uper Nick"; } };
const objB3 = { toString() { return "S4mm3r"; } };

const objL = { [Symbol.toPrimitive]() { return 10987654321; } };

console.log(formatValues(objB1, objL));
console.log(formatValues(objB2, objL));
console.log(formatValues(objB3, objL));
```

Which you can then use in your code:

```javascript
function ConcatenateJS() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    var valuesB = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lr,1).getValues();  //Get values for column B
    var valuesL = sheet.getRange(2, 12, lr,1).getValues();  //Get values for column L
    var results = [];                               //Create a empty array to be filled concatenated elements

    //Add items to results
    for(var i=0; i<lr; i++){
        results[i] = formatValues(valuesB[i][0], valuesL[i][0]);
    }

    //Post back to column 1 starting on row 2
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, 1).setValues(results);
}

function lettersOnly(svaluetr) {
  return String(value).replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
}

function numbersOnly(value) {
  return String(value).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}

function formatValues(str1, str2){ 
  var value1 = lettersOnly(str1).slice(0, 3);
  var value2 = numbersOnly(str2).slice(-8);
  
  return [value1 + "-" + value2];
}
```

Since Google Scripts supports modern ES6+ syntax, you can get slightly more compact code:

```js
const lettersOnly = value => String(value).replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
const numbersOnly = value => String(value).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

const formatValues = (str1, str2) => [
  `${lettersOnly(str1).slice(0, 3)}-${numbersOnly(str2).slice(-8)}`
];

console.log(formatValues("abcdef", "0987654321"));
console.log(formatValues("a1_b -2c-d4e5f", "q-1*r-2+s-3't-4-u-5_v-6 w-7,x-8.y-9(z-0"));
console.log(formatValues("ab6", "xyz12345"));

console.log(formatValues("Johnny", "0987654321"));
console.log(formatValues("S-Uper Nick", "0987654321"));
console.log(formatValues("S4mm3r", "0987654321"));

const objB1 = { toString() { return "Johnny"; } };
const objB2 = { toString() { return "S-Uper Nick"; } };
const objB3 = { toString() { return "S4mm3r"; } };

const objL = { [Symbol.toPrimitive]() { return 10987654321; } };

console.log(formatValues(objB1, objL));
console.log(formatValues(objB2, objL));
console.log(formatValues(objB3, objL));
```

Comment: Thank you VLAZ!
I copied and pasted your code, but I had this error: "str.replace is not a function".

Comment: What value do you get, in that case? I assumed it was a string but appears that it isn't.

Comment: Wait... I noticed that column L was in authomatic format. I've set in in text format, and now the functions work. But I don't get the values of columnL because they are only numbers.
In this case I should remove lettersOnly for value2, shouldn't I?

Comment: @ZeMatteis apparently [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2D array of objects. I guess, they must be convertible to strings. I have edited the code to do the conversion.

Comment: @ZeMatteis yes, if your L column doesn't have letters, you can remove it from there. As long as you only get a string, `slice(-8)` gets the last 8 characters from it. If you are getting a number instead, you can do `String(num).slice(-8)` which will turn `1234567890` into `"34567890"`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I solved it, and I added also a new function to take only numbers. I post it here, in the case someone else needs it:

function numbersOnly(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}

Comment: @ZeMatteis I have added it to the answer, so it's more visible and also added a bit of clarification.